# has_many relation with two foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, a city can have many links. A link connects two cities together and is bi-directional, as a consequence a link does not have a 'from' and 'to'. This results in the following `db schema`:

```
  create_table "links", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "endpoint1_id"
    t.integer "endpoint2_id"
    t.integer "capacity"
  end

  create_table "cities", force: true do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "lat"
    t.string "long"
  end
```

In my ActiveRecord models, I want to declare the relation between the two tables. Since I cannot seem to declare two foreign keys when setting up the `has_many` relation, I I worked around that like this:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base    
  # has_many with two foreign keys?
  # has_many :links
  def links
    Link.where("endpoint1_id=? OR links.endpoint2_id=?", id, id)
  end    
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :endpoint1, :class_name => 'City'
  belongs_to :endpoint2, :class_name => 'City'
end
```

This allows me to do: `City.find(1).links` but seems not a proper solution and does not enforce any inheritance. Also, from a `link` I cannot find the relation city unless I go through both the `city.endpoint1` and `city.endpoint2`.

Are there more elegant solutions to defining a `has_many` relation with two foreign keys? Or should I maybe step away from this approach and somehow change my `db schema`?

Comment: can you rewrite the first line of your question? You want city to have many links and also have city-link-city connection?

Comment: Maybe you could work with to sets of `has_many` for example `has_many :links_to` and `has_many :links_from`. And then do more or less what you are doing now?

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the same issue as with the "friendships" in facebook-like applications, where one user follows another, and is they both follow each other, they are friends. I had this before and I solved it by joining the Friendships table against itself, which would give all friendships that are mutual. The difference here is that the connections are always present, regardless of directions, but in general I see the same problem I faced before. 
My suggestion would be:

1. When creating Links, always create them bothways, 
   Link.new(endpoint1_id: city_1_id, endpoint2_id: city_2_id)
   Link.new(endpoint2_id: city_1_id, endpoint1_id: city_2_id)
2. Then when searching from connections coming from one city, make an sql statement selecting from cities and links like this:

   ```
   def connections # find your cities, where connections run both ways
   City.find_by_sql "
   select * from cities
     where id in
       (select f2.endpoint1_id from links as f1 inner join links as f2 on (f1.endpoint1_id = f2.endpoint2_id) and (f1.endpoint2_id = f2.endpoint1_id) and (f1.endpoint1_id = #{id.to_i}))" # normally this can cause an sql injection, but here it is handled by to_i
   end
   ```

This solution may not be the optimal one for this issue, but it is definitely more flexible, since it will also allow you to handle one-way connections the same way.